# How to create a custom login function (Using Curl) in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, curl

My aim is really simple, but I tried to search all the documents online and I have no valid result.

I am still quite new to Symfony, so I probably would need more explanations.

So I followed all the instructions in this page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

However, I am stuck on this example code here, which I don't know what to implement.

```
// make a call to your webservice here
$userData = ...
// pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

if ($userData) {
    $password = '...';

    // ...
```

I would like to use my own function to login a third party website. As due to it is an unofficial login (Regardless the security), I will be using `Curl` and check the `Set-Cookie` header inside it.

Here is an example that I will use without symfony:

```
function checkLogin($username, $password) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$username&password=$password");

    $header = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    return (bool)preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $header);
} //Return true = username and password is correct, hence I can follow up on my own site.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer was useful for you, accept it. If it does not completely answer your question, please clarify what is not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `Token`, `Listener` that will create Token from your user's request and `AuthenticationProvider` implementing `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface`.

Here is example implementation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Don't hesitate to ask questions about it and check if their cross-origin policy allows requests from your host.

Comment: Thanks for the info, How can I modify the `The Authentication Provider`'s `authenticate` function and implement my function? Or am I looking at the wrong place? Thanks

Comment: You can modify it as much as you want:) Authentication logic is called exactly inside that function. Requests to external API, in your case.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, After following all the steps in the website (Literally copied all the code), i got this error message: https://pastebin.com/3U59zmFY. How can I resolve it? thanks

Comment: I guess you don't have this service "security.authentication.provider.wsse.wsse_secured" defined. Most likely a typo. Show services.yml, where you register this service and where you use(inject) it.

Comment: Next time please update your question or ask another one. Avoid asking new questions in comments, since SO is not only for you and me, but also for others, who will come from google.